# How can I wipe a logical partition from a bootable usb?

Tags: partition, windows-10, formatting

I'm looking for a way to wipe just one partition from the drive.
Currently I have a recovery partition which needs to stay as it is and a partition with windows 10 installed which needs to be wiped.

I've looked in to DBAN, but it seems it can wipe only a complete drive.

Are there any free tools?
Is it possible to to do this with a bootable Ubuntu USB?

Answer (score 0):

On any linux distro, you can do:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdbX
```

After zeroing the partition, you'll perhaps want to remove the partition itself, which you can do with `diskpart`, `fdisk`, or any number of other tools.